# How to stretch text in PHP using GD?

Tags: php, gd, captcha

Is it possible to stretch text using GD in PHP? I need it for captcha, like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKEbD.gif)(right captcha).

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.distortimage.php

Comment: GD Library doesn't have this function. You can use imagick instead. If you don't have access to that, there is a "dirty" solution that you can always use. And that is create separate images for each letter and number and distort them to you heart's content in your graphic program and just load each character's image into gd library.

Comment: "Warp" would probably be a better research keyword here, than "stretch."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample taken from [here](https://www.html-code-generator.com/php/captcha-image-code-generator), there are bunch of options to create a captcha per your needs.

**captcha-image.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    //PHP CAPTCHA image
    //Generated by https://www.html-code-generator.com/php/captcha-image-code-generator


    $width = 130;
    $height = 30;
    $font_size = 20;
    $font = "./verdana.ttf";
    $font = realpath($font);
    $chars_length = 4;

    $captcha_characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
    $font_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $bg_color);

    //background random-line
    $vert_line = round($width/5);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    for($i=0; $i < $vert_line; $i++) {
        imageline($image, rand(0,$width), rand(0,$height), rand(0,$height), rand(0,$width), $color);
    }

    $xw = ($width/$chars_length);
    $x = 0;
    $font_gap = $xw/2-$font_size/2;
    $digit = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $chars_length; $i++) {
        $letter = $captcha_characters[rand(0, strlen($captcha_characters)-1)];
        $digit .= $letter;
        if ($i == 0) {
            $x = 0;
        }else {
            $x = $xw*$i;
        }
        imagettftext($image, $font_size, rand(-20,20), $x+$font_gap, rand(22, $height-5), $font_color, $font, $letter);
    }

    // record token in session variable
    $_SESSION['captcha_token'] = strtolower($digit);

    // display image
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP CAPTCHA Test Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="p-5">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Message</div>
            <div class="card-body">

                <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">
                    <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Message *</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Captcha *</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                                <div class="col mb-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="token" id="token" placeholder="Captcha" style="min-width: 150px;">
                                </div>

                                <div class="col mb-3">
                                    <img src="./captcha/image.php?12325" alt="CAPTCHA" id="image-captcha">
                                    <a href="#" id="refresh-captcha" class="align-middle" title="refresh"><i class="material-icons align-middle">refresh</i></a>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit">submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        var refreshButton = document.getElementById("refresh-captcha");
        var captchaImage = document.getElementById("image-captcha");

        refreshButton.onclick = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            captchaImage.src = './captcha/image.php?' + Date.now();
        };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    if ( isset($_POST['message'], $_POST['token']) ) {

        
        $token = strtolower($_POST['token']);

        // validate captcha code        
        if (isset($_SESSION['captcha_token']) && $_SESSION['captcha_token'] == $token) {

            //success your code here

            $to = "somebody@example.com";
            $subject = "subject";
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .  "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
            
            //mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

            echo "success";

        } else {
            echo "error CAPTCHA code";
        }
        
    }
?>
```